# Flat File Photo Rating Script Questions

Tags: php, flat-file

I have a very limited server environment. I can't even use JSON. I have created a page with about 25 photos on it. When you roll over the photo a 5 star rating div appears, you can click on the stars you think the photo should be rated at.

I have looked online at some tutorials and what not and got a JSON version going, then put it on the server and blah... nothing. No JSON. Should have checked that huH? Well, I know I can write to text files, so I am going that route.  I followed this tut: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/ to get it running on my images. Works just like it want it to... however, not on the server without JSON.

SO! What I want to know is, how can I make this write to a flat file? I can use the .POST{} jquery function and call a php script, but I am lost at how to post the data to the file.

Thanks for any thoughts, ideas, or the like. :)

Comment: Updated your tags. You want to know how to use PHP to write a text file, jQuery has not much to do with that.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but "Can't even use JSON" - does that mean you're still on PHP 4? Then consider changing hosts, PHP 4 is really, really dead

Comment: it's a enterprise deal. If I had my choice, I'd have php5 on everything for sure. way nicer!

Answer (score 1):

I've used json on PHP4 boxes. Simply use:

http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/

Then, in your code do something along the lines of:

```
if (!function_exists('json_encode')) {
    require_once('services_json.php');
    $_JSON = new Services_JSON();

    function json_encode($value, $options = 0)
    {
        global $_JSON;
        return $_JSON->encode($value);
    }

    function json_decode($str, $assoc = false, $depth = 512)
    {
        global $_JSON;
        return $_JSON->decode($str);
    }
}
```

This has allowed me to use json_encode/decode functions without worrying about PHP version.

Comment: I have tried this in the past, but will give it a shot again and report back. Thanks!

Comment: does that require me to add it to the PHP setup? I don't have that access.

Comment: No, you can just include it like any other PHP file. Just go to http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/download and download it from the "For manual installation only" link. Unzip it and throw it wherever you want. It doesn't depend on other PEAR files.